# How to calculate percentile in a pd dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Trying to calculate the percentile of a value in a pd column but only for x number of values:

```
Column name = 'Signal'
50
20
30
20
102
22
1
2
43
49
38
173
371
312
```

Next to each value would like to calculate on a rolling basis the percentile of that value among X numbers preceding that one (inclusive).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scipy.stats.rankdata()` to calculate your data's rank and `pd.rolling()` to calculate the rank on a rolling basis.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import rankdata

df = pd.DataFrame({'Signal':[50,20,30,20,102,22,1,2,43,49,38,173,371,312]})

def last_value_rank(arr): 
    """
    Calculates the last value's rank. 
    Rankings start from 1. 
    Duplicates are considered (e.g. [1,3,2,2] ranks are [1,4,2.5,2.5], result = 2.5)
    """
    return rankdata(arr)[-1]

def last_value_rank_normalized(arr):
    return (last_value_rank(arr) - 1) * 100 / (len(arr) - 1)

print(df.join(df['Signal'].rolling(5).agg([last_value_rank, last_value_rank_normalized])))
```

output:

```
    Signal  last_value_rank  last_value_rank_normalized
0       50              NaN                         NaN
1       20              NaN                         NaN
2       30              NaN                         NaN
3       20              NaN                         NaN
4      102              5.0                       100.0
5       22              3.0                        50.0
6        1              1.0                         0.0
7        2              2.0                        25.0
8       43              4.0                        75.0
9       49              5.0                       100.0
10      38              3.0                        50.0
11     173              5.0                       100.0
12     371              5.0                       100.0
13     312              4.0                        75.0
```

Comment: Thank you for this. It seems your suggestion is asking for a specific percentile and obtaining an output.

What if you wanted to see which percentile a given value represented in the array. For example, if we roll based on 5 values, the first result would come at index 4:

[50,20,30,20,102] >> output the percentile of '102' amongst those numbers, then
[20,30,20,102,22] >> output the percentile of '22' amongst those numbers, and so on.. on a rolling basis.

I hope that's clear...

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Based on your explanation, what you are looking for is the data's **rank**, not the percentile. Consider updating your question with the correct terminology and include the sample you've shown in your comment to help other people who might have the same issue.

Comment: Updated my answer to fit your clarification. Please let me know if I missed something.